# Android inapp billing - Giving Credit card details at Runtime

Tags: android, in-app-billing

We have inApp billing in out application. We have planned to scan the Cards for the details and make the payment.

Is it possible to fill credit card details at runtime from code in Google inApp billing or we should use third party payment process. Please help me on this.

I came across card.io . I can scanning Credit card using this jar. but I don't know how to add those details to google in-app billing system programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't handle CC input. Google Play is handling Credit Card data, and this is a good thing - it prevents 3rd parties from stealing the CC information.